# How do I rewrite the below Oracle trigger so it will work on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger

I am migrating from Oracle to SQL Server using SSMA and I get thrown an unparsed SQL error on the below code. Can anyone help me convert this to T-SQL? Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ISTRAINING"."INSERT_COURSE_DELEGATES" BEFORE 
INSERT ON "COURSE_DELEGATES" FOR EACH ROW declare
 row_locked exception;
 pragma exception_init (row_locked, -54);
begin
 begin
  select next 
  into :new.COURSE_DELE_ID
  from ISTRAINING.sequence
  where tname='COURSE_DELEGATES' and tcolname='COURSE_DELE_ID'
  for update of next nowait;
  exception
  when row_locked then
      raise_application_error (-20002,'Database temporarily locked'); 
 end;
 update ISTRAINING.sequence
 set next=next+1
 where tname='COURSE_DELEGATES' and tcolname='COURSE_DELE_ID';  
end;
```

Comment: The real question is: why didn't you use a **real** sequence in Oracle to begin with?

Comment: I didn't write the code, I've just inherited it and been tasked with the migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news is that SQL Server doesn't support `FOR EACH ROW` triggers, so you'd have to take extra care to convert the trigger code.

The good news is that this appears to just be doing what can be achieved with an `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server, and you won't need the trigger at all.

In your `CREATE TABLE COURSE_DELEGATES...` statement, declare the `COURSE_DELE_ID` column something like this (use a more appropriate data type if it isn't `int`):

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE_DELEGATES (
    COURSE_DELE_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    ....
)
```

Then any rows inserted in `COURSE_DELEGATES` will get an auto-generated value for `COURSE_DELE_ID`, starting with 1, and incrementing by 1 for each new row.

Comment: Or use a Sequence object in SQL 2012+  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: A Sequence is better as it _allows_ you to generate the values first and then insert them, which is more compatible with the model you have in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've used this solution and it's fixed after days of going over it. Appreciate it!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, though in this case, it appears that the Oracle trigger isn't doing anything with the values prior to inserting them, and doesn't appear to have multiple parallel sequences in the same table, so for this situation, a simple `IDENTITY` column will reduce maintenance overhead. If the application ever needs to preview the new values *before* the insert happens, or needs to generate multiple sequences within the same table based on different columns (a bit like MySQL can do with MyISAM), then you'll definitely need a sequence object.

Comment: Oh, though I believe there are some performance improvements you can get from a sequence (correct me if I'm wrong here), so if this is a *heavily* loaded OLTP application with tons of inserts, then that may make it worth the effort to set up a sequence object.

Comment: Sequence object and Identity columns use the same mechanism internally, so you should not see any significant performance differences between them.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sequence objects have the `CACHE` property; do `IDENTITY` columns make use of that same caching capability behind the scenes? But yes, you'd have to be doing a ridiculous amount of inserts before that becomes significant.

Comment: Yes.  IDENTITY columns use the same caching capabilities behind the scenes.  Turning off the caching on either one forces a transaction log write after each value is generated.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Good to know, thanks for clarifying that point.

Answer (score 0):

## Gap Free Sequential Number

The Oracle code implements a "gap free sequential number" Business Requirement for the ID column.

It appears that the table used to maintain "current ID" is used for multiple tables.

**Get rid of this Business Requirement ASAP!!!!**

"Gap free sequential numbers" should only be used for Human consumption after you have upper management sign (in triplicate) that they are OK with the known performance trade-off.

Primary reason I've seen for such Business Requirement is for Auditors.  Sadly, this comes from a paper world where "paper trails" are made of ... paper.  In the digital age, there are other ways to see if someone has modified data or a missed "Invoice"/"PO" number was (never) used.

One "valid usage" would be for document Revision/Version numbers.

Even then, when "gap free sequential numbers" are used, **you should use a surrogate key as the PK**.

## Recommendation

1. Get approval to remove the "gap free sequential number" requirement.
2. Drop the trigger and use a `SEQUENCE`/`IDENTITY` column.